# Rails Simple Form :first :last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, simple-form

Writing a fairly long form using the simple form gem but having trouble with the radio button collections. Users are asked questions and have radio buttons to choose from but the value to be entered is different than what is being displayed for the user. Here is an example line of my code,

```
  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :shower_flow_rate, prompt: "Do you have low flow shower heads?",[[2.5, 'Yes'] ,[3.8, 'Some'], [5.0, 'No']], :first, :last%>
```

:shower_flow_rate is the variable I want filled. What are :first and :last? Are they necessary? I found very little documentation explaining the :first and :last.

Also I have several attributes in the same schema that need to be filled by calculating the sum or product of some of these inputs in the form. Should these values be calculated in the view or in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

In you case yes they are necessary, [`first`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-first) & [`last`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-last) are array methods. `(You can use any methods instead of :first, :last which is valid for the each element of the collection)`
Ref [`collection_radio_buttons`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons)

In you case following is collection

```
[[2.5, 'Yes'] ,[3.8, 'Some'], [5.0, 'No']]
So, :first & :last are the methods which will call on each 
element of the collection to create an HTML
# For Ex:- 
# [2.5, 'Yes'].first => 2.5
# [2.5, 'Yes'].last => 'Yes'
```

Comment: So :shower_flow_rate will register as an attribute while :first is a method to store the first value in the array as the attribute. Why would I need :last then if I only want the 'Yes' displayed but never saved?

Comment: Yes, first i.e. `2.5` is the value of the radio button whereas `Yes` will be label for that radio button. In other words whenever you select radio button with label `Yes` it's value `2.5` will be send in the parameters.